# jQuery Multiple Select Event when done selecting

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, materialize, onchange

I have a `<select>` input field that has the `multiple` flag enabled so a user can select multiple options at once.

When I add the `change()` event, it runs whenever the user selects a new option. Is there a way to have a function run when the user is done selecting their options?

Here is what I currently have:

```
$("#myselect").change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Currently this runs *every* time a new option is selected. I would like to have it run once the select list is closed.

Edit: My HTML is the basic code from MaterializeCSS

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select name="myselect" multiple>
      <option value="All" selected>All</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
  </div>
```

What I am trying to do is have it so if 'All' is selected, and another option is picked, it will deselect 'All'. When using MaterializeCSS framework, when I run `$("#myselect").formSelect();`, it defocuses the select dropdown so I am trying to only have it run once when the user is done selecting their options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a function run when the user is done selecting their options?

You can use [dropdownOptions](https://materializecss.com/select.html) option:

```
$('#myselect').formSelect({
    dropdownOptions: {
        onCloseEnd: function(e) {
            console.log(e.value);
        }
    }
});
```

> if 'All' is selected, and another option is picked, it will deselect 'All'.

In order to achieve that your **change** event could be:

```
$("#myselect").on('change', function(e){
    var selectedItems = $(this).val() || [];
    // if All and another option(s) are selected....
    if (selectedItems.length > 1 && selectedItems.indexOf('All') >= 0) {
        // deselect All....
        $(this).siblings('ul.select-dropdown')
                   .find('li.selected:contains(All)').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

```js
$('#myselect').formSelect({
    dropdownOptions: {
        onCloseEnd: function(e) {
            console.log(e.value);
        }
    }
});

$("#myselect").on('change', function(e){
  var selectedItems = $(this).val() || [];
  if (selectedItems.length > 1 && selectedItems.indexOf('All') >= 0) {
      $(this).siblings('ul.select-dropdown').find('li.selected:contains(All)').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <br>
                <p>Demo.......</p>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                <select id="myselect" name="myselect" multiple>
                    <option value="All" selected>All</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
                <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This works only once. If a user selects a different option and then wants to click All again, it wont work

Comment: @Bijan Indeed. You asked to deselect all options if All option is selected. Please, clarify how should it work. Thanks

Comment: I made it so if All is selected, it will do `$(this).siblings('ul.select-dropdown').find('li.selected:not(:contains(All))').trigger('click');` to unselect everything

Comment: @Bijan I see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do you determine when the user is done selecting? You can try other events besides `change()`.

such as `focusout()` or `keyup()`

see: https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: I assume they are done selecting when the dropdown closes. `focusout` is never triggered on a select dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If other solutions doesn't work, try `blur`, it worked for me.

```
$("#myselect").on('blur', function(e){
    // your code
});
```